# how to justify left all numbered equations

Tags: equations, lyx, align, elsarticle

I use displayed numberd formula in lyx

the equations are appears in middel

I want to justify left the equations

I used elsarticl 2 column page format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class option `fleqn` helps. The math indent can be configured via length `\mathindent`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Example equation:
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\noindent
Equation with zeroed math indent:
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: how to do this in lyx? i don't know how to put code

Answer (score 1):

It works
tools->setting->document class

in class options put fleqn

before the first equation put the code like this

insert->tex code

in the box appears write

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

and

\noindent

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this option

> *Indented* for this the option `fleqn` must be inserted in the menu `Document ▷ Settings` under `Document Class`